# Following Parameter was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a code on button click. When I run this code, I get error as

> *The parameterized query '(@CatName nvarchar(9),@Parent_Id int)Insert into tbl_Category(Ca' expects the parameter '@Parent_Id', which was
>   not supplied.*

My logic here is

If I select the value of dropdown and add text and then Click the submit button, The textbox value will become the Child value of the Selected Value from the dropdownlist. Please see the code:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ParentId = null;

    if (ddlCategory.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        ParentId = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
    }
    string query = "Insert into tbl_Category(CatName,Parent_Id) values (@CatName,@Parent_Id)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@CatName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAddCategories.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Parent_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (ParentId != null ? ParentId : null);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Do let me know where is the error ?

Comment: Is there any difference between `ParentId` and `(ParentId != null ? ParentId : null);` ?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` and pass the correct type(`int` instead of `string`):

```
object pID = DBNull.Value;
if(ParentID != null) pID = int.Parse(ParentId);
command.Parameters.Add("@Parent_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pID;
```

Because there was some confusion (see comments and chat), here is the complete code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ParentId = null;

    if (ddlCategory.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        ParentId = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
    }
    string query = "Insert into tbl_Category(CatName,Parent_Id) values (@CatName,@Parent_Id)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@CatName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAddCategories.Text;
            object pID = DBNull.Value;
            if(ParentID != null) pID = int.Parse(ParentId);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Parent_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pID;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I select the value from dropdownlist, it does not become as the Child of the selected value

Comment: @RahulSutar: are you asking us to fix your logic or to fix the database error?

Comment: I want to fix this logic, As the value is getting inserted but it is not showing in the table as expected

Comment: @RahulSutar: what do you expect, what is inserted actually? If the error mentioned in your questions is fixed you should consider to ask another question since it's getting too broad otherwise.

Comment: See, If I dont select any value from the dropdownlist and add text in the textbox, The ParentId should go as NULL. And If I select value from the dropdownlist and add the text and submit. Then the added text should become the child of the selected value from the dropdownlist

Comment: @RahulSutar: i understand, but is the `Parent_Id` value inserted successfully? Because i don't understand your comment _"value is getting inserted but it is not showing in the table as expected"_. That seems to be a contradiction, isn't it?

Comment: yes the `Parent_Id` is inserted successfully, but NULL everytime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68803/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-tim-schmelter).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, the placement of code was the issue. Now it is resolved..!!

Answer (score 1):

Change you code like this:-

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Parent_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ParentId ?? DBNull.Value;
```

The problem in your code is that `ternary operator` is not able to determine the return type because you are either returning an `int` value or `null` value, which are obviously not compatible. So you can use `Null Coalesce` operator instead.

Comment: @RahulSutar - Which class? As you can see I have changed just a single line i.e. I have just introduced `DBNull` class which is present in `System` namespace, and I am sure your code includes this namespace. So your error has something to do with your code.